# Intuit Customer Account Data API and Categorization

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

In reference to the Customer Account Data API, is there a way to get a listing of all possible categories that Intuit uses to categorize a transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_aggregation_categorization_apps/0005_service_features/0055_types_of_categories for a complete list of categories available.

Comment: Thank you. It's an informative site, but sometimes it's hard to find what you're looking for (even after the redesign).